# A way to copy data from android?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-4, locked-out

I have a samsung s4 on android 6.0.1 and the phone has a cracked and unresponsive screen. I tried to plug the phone to my computer so see if I could copy pictures from my internal drive but it wouldn't work. I tried  `adb pull` since I have root access and developer option was always enabled but I get `error: insufficient permissions for device: verify udev rules.`
`adb devices`  shows `9a22b563  no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]` I think this is happening because of my locked screen. It is stopping adb from working properly. Is there a way to get my data back by disabling the lock screen?
I have root and custom recovery access but unable to reboot to recovery due to adb not giving access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually boot to recovery without adb. Therefore turn your phone off and then press the power button, home button and volume up (at least as far as I remember) simultaneously for several seconds. This should boot the phone to recovery and you can try to use adb although I don't know if you now have the needed permissions.